# Stripping strings within a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to strip characters from the end of every string in a list of strings.

What I do not understand is how this doesn't work:

```
def test():
    listymclist = ['bla bla bla\n', 'stuff\n', '80085\n']

    for entry in listymclist:
        entry.strip('\n')

    return listymclist
```

The end result is listymclist unaltered: `['bla bla bla\n', 'stuff\n', '80085\n']`

But if I do this instead:

```
def test():
    listymclist = ['bla bla bla\n', 'stuff\n', '80085\n']

    listymclist = [x.strip('\n') for x in listymclist]

    return listymclist
```

I get my list back in the desired stripped form: `['bla bla bla', 'stuff', '80085']`

In the first example, it seems like my for loop is completely ignored as if the changes to the list haven't been amended to listymclist. Why is this extra step  `listmclist = ...`  necessary since it is a list and not something immutable like a tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first loop is not mutating the entries in listmyclist. Your operation strips the `\n` but never writes the value back to your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for entry in listymclist:
    entry.strip('\n')
```

The strip() method call returns a copy of the string with stripping, it does not modify the original. This is because python strings are immutable.See this example to be clear:

```
str = "0000000this is string example....wow!!!0000000";
print str.strip( '0' )
print str
```

Output will be:

```
this is string example....wow!!!
0000000this is string example....wow!!!0000000
```

Therefore in the first example you are calling strip() on the string, but throwing away the stripped version (not assigning it to anything) and the original string stays unmodified.

But inside the second one.

```
listymclist = [x.strip('\n') for x in listymclist]
```

you are creating a new list of strings which are the return values from calling strip() on the originals. Thus this new list will contain stripped versions.Finally you are reassigning the list inside listymclist. So, now it will contain the modified version.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the function str.strip() returns a copy of the string within the list, which is not being appended to your list 'listymclist'. It returns a copy because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

[`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method does not change original string instead it returns copy of string. You can put returned value in another list and then return that list

```
def test():
    listymclist = ['bla bla bla\n', 'stuff\n', '80085\n']
    stripped_list = []
    for entry in listymclist:
        stripped_list.append(entry.strip('\n'))

    return stripped_list
```

Comment: Is using a new list   that efficient? what if the list size is huge? can't we change the string with the list index in place? what do you think?

Comment: It is as good as list comprehension. List comprehension does the same thing

Comment: I am thinking about using range in the first example and after calling the string.strip() store it in a variable then finally push it on that particular index. I don't know, kind of memory efficient may be, though i myself don't convinced that is a good design

Comment: Yes, you can change individual list elements in place - see my answer. Yes, if the list is enormous, this will avoid needing RAM to store both all the elements of the original list and the elements of the new list at the same time.  But unless you are dealing with enormous lists or code to work in an embedded system (such as an OpenWRT router), code what's clearest not what saves RAM.

Comment: A list comprehension is not exactly  the same thing as a list, unless you wrap it in square brackets and assign it to something to  force it to generate a list. In Python 3, try `z = ( x**2 for x in range(10) )` and the interpreter will tell you that z is a "generator object". Then do `for i in z: print(i)`. No list needed! Makes a difference for a very long sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The python `for x in alist` syntax is *usually* preferable to indexing a list, but not always. If you want to modify elements of the list, you have to index them in order to assign to them. So:

```
for i in in range( len(listymclist)):
   listymclist[i] = listymclist[i].strip()
```

Some might prefer

```
for i, x in enumerate(listymclist):
   listymclist[i] = x.strip()
```